# Is it possible to add an Angular component within an existing pure Javascript project?

Tags: javascript, angular

**I want to add/create a new Angular component inside an existing pure Javascript library so that the library can be easily integrated within Angular apps**.  The Angular component will essentially be a wrapper for the library.  We already added a React wrapper to the library for this same purpose.

Given that Angular is a framework solution, and I don't want to drastically change the structure of the existing JS project, **is it possible to add Angular to the existing JS project?**  If so, how is that done from a high-level?  I normally use Angular-cli v6 in my other projects.

Comment: I've seen this done with angularJS (not Angular), but I don't recommend it. But you may be able to set your page up as an angular app and your other javascript should still run normally.

Comment: since angular 6 release the introduce to angular element check my answer @Mayhem50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

Angular elements are Angular components packaged as custom elements, a web standard for defining new HTML elements in a framework-agnostic way.

[Building a Custom Element Using Angular Elements](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/building-a-custom-element-using-angular-elements/)

[Angular Elements — A Practical Introduction To Web Components With Angular 6](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-elements-a-practical-introduction-to-web-components-with-angular-6-52c0b3076c2c)

Browser support for custom elements

> **Chrome**    Supported natively.
>
> **Opera**     Supported natively.
>
> **Safari**    Supported natively.
>
> **Firefox**   Set the `dom.webcomponents.enabled` and `dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled`
> preferences to `true`. Planned to be enabled by default in version
> **60/61**.
>
> **Edge**  Working on an implementation.